# Array Shifting to get file name out of a string

Tags: php, arrays, model-view-controller

How to extract (file name) `ContractController` (controller class) from the path `‘Info/ContactController’`?

The code below

```
<?php

$path_to_controller = 'Info/ContactController’';
$path_explode = explode('/', str_replace('./', '', (string)$path_to_controller));
var_dump($path_explode);
```

got me to

> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Info" [1]=> string(17) "ContactController"
>   }

Now, I need to array_shift the variable `$path_explode` to get `ContactController` and assign it to `$file` but am unable to.

Can you help?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Comment: Why not use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) instead? When PHP has a built-in function to do this for you, why do you want to write your own? `$file = pathinfo($path_to_controller)['filename'];`

Comment: $file = $path_explode[1]; //ContactController

Answer (score 0):

[basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) would be the shortest and precise way to achieve this.

```
<?php

$path_to_controller = 'Info/ContactController';

echo basename($path_to_controller);
```

Output : `ContactController`